# Nginx ingress controller not giving metrics for prometheus

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, prometheus-operator

I am trying to deploy an nginx ingress controller which can be monitored using prometheus however I am running into an issue that it seems no metrics pod(s) is being created like most posts and docs I have found online show.

I'm using helm to deploy the ingress controller and using a CLI arguement to enable metrics.

```
helm install ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.metrics.enabled=true
```

Here is my ingress file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    # add an annotation indicating the issuer to use.
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-dev"
    # needed to allow the front end to talk to the back end
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://app.domain.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    # needed for monitoring
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "10254"
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: development
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.<domain>.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 8090
        path: /
  tls: # < placing a host in the TLS config will indicate a certificate should be created
  - hosts:
    - api.<domai>.com
    secretName: dev-ingress-cert # < cert-manager will store the created certificate in this secre
```

In case this makes a difference I am using the prometheus operator helm chart with the below command.

```
helm install monitoring stable/prometheus-operator --namespace=monitoring
```

All namespaces exist already so that shouldn't be an issue, as for the development vs monitoring name spaces I saw in many places this was acceptable so I went with it to make things easier to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 7):

I would follow this [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/monitoring.md) to setup monitoring for Nginx ingress controller. I believe what you are missing is a [prometheus.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/prometheus/prometheus.yaml) which defines scrape config for the Nginx ingress controller and [RBAC](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/prometheus/role.yaml) for prometheus to be able to scrape the Nginx ingress controller metrics.

**Edit:** Annotate nginx ingress controller pods

```
kubectl annotate pods nginx-ingress-controller-pod prometheus.io/scrape=true -n ingress-nginx --overwrite

kubectl annotate pods nginx-ingress-controller-pod prometheus.io/port=10254  -n ingress-nginx --overwrite
```

Comment: After following the Nginx guide the metrics don't seem to be caught by Prometheus. The grafana dashboard is empty i.e. values are N/A. Are there any additional steps I need to do? The guide doesn't mention them...

Comment: No, all of the logs (about 10) are `level=info`. They seem like regular startup logs to me.

Comment: Prometheus and nginx ingress controller are deployed in the same namespace?

Comment: Yup, same namespace for nginx ingress controller, prometheus and grafana.

Comment: What is the name of the namespace?

Comment: `ingress-nginx`, same as the one from the nginx guide. I've followed the guide from the helm install up until the very last screenshot (which is missing the values...)

Comment: Describe the nginx ingress controller deployment and see if it has got an annotation prometheus.io/scrape: true

Comment: It doesn't. Do I just `kubectl edit` on the deployment? And add this `prometheus.io/scrape: "true"` ?

Comment: Any restarts / reloads needed? I've edited the deployment but no change in the values thus far.

Comment: I've added the `scrape: "true"` into one of the Ingress resources I have running but still there is no data in grafana / no new logs in the prometheus pod

Comment: Status - Service Discovery in the Prometheus UI shows this: `ingress-nginx-endpoints (0/5 active targets)`

Comment: Add annotations : kubectl annotate pods nginx-ingress-controller-859f5d6bcd-zcntr prometheus.io/scrape=true  -n ingress-nginx
kubectl annotate pods nginx-ingress-controller-859f5d6bcd-zcntr prometheus.io/port=10254  -n ingress-nginx

Comment: It seems to be working now. Athough when I restarted the pods with `scrape: "false"` it still works for some reason. Oh well :) Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: I have a new k8s cluster with only Prometheus, Grafana, Nginx Ingress Controller and Cert Manager installed (all via Helm). At the moment this command doesn't do anything. :( Not really sure why it started working the last time... Anything else you could think of?

Comment: the missing Prometheus worked for , the only thing additionally i had to do was to delete the Prometheus setup and recreated  it.And it worked. for me this [guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/prometheus-kubernetes-monitoring)  worked for installation of standalone Prometheus

Answer (score 1):

I was not using helm but manifests and the method POD annotations to install the Prometheus. I follow the [official doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/monitoring/) but could not see the metric either.

I believe the Deployment manifest has some issues. The annotation shouldn't be put on the Deployment level but on the pod level

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
..
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
    label:
      ...
  ports:
    - name: prometheus
      containerPort: 10254
      ..
```

Also, I've confirmed the metric for Nginx is enabled by default when using manifest deployment. No extra steps are needed for this.